# Finding the best lag for features in time-series regression

Tags: regression, time-series

Hej,
I am trying to predict the price of renting a special type of asset(time-series on a daily level). To do this I have five years' worth of data. The dataset contains of prices for different commodities which has some correlation with the renting price of the asset price I am trying to predict.
I know that there is a lag. For example, oil prices 7 days ago are likely better predicting the price of my asset than oil prices of the same day.

What method should I be using to find the lag with the best correlation?

Answer (score 0):

> What method should I be using to find the lag with the best
> correlation?

That can be seen in the autocorrelation curve.

Or, in a broader sense, one other good heuristic would be using [Persistence models](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/persistence-model#:%7E:text=The%20persistence%20model%20considers%20that,also%20called%20the%20na%C3%AFve%20predictor.), and see if which lag (or which weighted average of the last $n$ lags of the same multiple) best predicts the current day, according to your choice of error metric.